# Eclipse crash while editing code

Tags: android, eclipse

When I try to write code in MainActivity.java, Eclipse crashes and the hs_err_pid8689.log file is generated in the Eclipse folder. Can anyone help figure out what's going wrong?

The error log is:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x57fb286d, pid=8689, tid=3075802880
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5486d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x08c09400):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=8689, stack(0xbf883000,0xbf8d3000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x09029b58, EBX=0x57fed000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000001
ESP=0xbf8d0920, EBP=0xbf8d0958, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x08c09400
EIP=0x57fb286d, EFLAGS=0x00210282, CR2=0x00000000

Top of Stack: (sp=0xbf8d0920)
0xbf8d0920:   5f89233a 09029b58 b7701e49 5f8930e8
0xbf8d0930:   57fb2857 5f8930e8 a55dbe94 5f88f2aa
0xbf8d0940:   00000000 09b87528 08c09400 5f88f22b
0xbf8d0950:   b2338aee a55dbe98 bf8d099c b2338bf3
0xbf8d0960:   08c09530 bf8d09a4 00000000 09b87528
0xbf8d0970:   08c09530 bf8d09ac 77a60f38 bf8d097c
0xbf8d0980:   a55dbe94 bf8d09b0 a55e1520 00000000
0xbf8d0990:   a55dbe98 00000000 bf8d09ac bf8d09d4 

Instructions: (pc=0x57fb286d)
0x57fb284d:   74 26 00 56 53 e8 79 73 fc ff 81 c3 a9 a7 03 00
0x57fb285d:   83 ec 14 8b 74 24 20 e8 a7 fc ff ff 89 44 24 04
0x57fb286d:   8b 06 89 04 24 e8 b9 51 fc ff 8b 54 24 24 89 34
0x57fb287d:   24 89 54 24 04 ff 50 0c 83 c4 14 5b 5e c3 90 8d 

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x09029b58 is an unknown value
EBX=0x57fed000: <offset 0x8f000> in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1 at 0x57f5e000
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000001 is an unknown value
ESP=0xbf8d0920 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x08c09400
EBP=0xbf8d0958 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x08c09400
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x08c09400 is a thread


Stack: [0xbf883000,0xbf8d3000],  sp=0xbf8d0920,  free space=310k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5486d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK._soup_session_feature_detach(II)V+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK.soup_session_feature_detach(II)V+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebKit.create(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+892
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+81
j  org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl.isAvailable(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+12
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover$HoverControlCreator.doCreateInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+18
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator.createInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.getInformationControl()Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+176
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.internalShowInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/Rectangle;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+18
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.presentInformation()V+70
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractHoverInformationControlManager.presentInformation()V+64
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager.doPresentInformation()V+1
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$5.run()V+4
J 3988 C1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z (101 bytes) @ 0xb2b74410 [0xb2b742d0+0x140]
J 3993 C1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z (71 bytes) @ 0xb2b75e48 [0xb2b75d70+0xd8]
J 4117% C1 org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V (745 bytes) @ 0xb2bb76e0 [0xb2bb6080+0x1660]
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+256
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x2ae025]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x315
V  [libjvm.so+0x4030b9]  os::os_exception_wrapper(void (*)(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*), JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x19
V  [libjvm.so+0x2acc9f]  JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x2f
V  [libjvm.so+0x448fbe]  Reflection::invoke(instanceKlassHandle, methodHandle, Handle, bool, objArrayHandle, BasicType, objArrayHandle, bool, Thread*)+0x3fe
V  [libjvm.so+0x449a7a]  Reflection::invoke_method(oopDesc*, Handle, objArrayHandle, Thread*)+0x15a
V  [libjvm.so+0x3314d9]  JVM_InvokeMethod+0x209
C  [libjava.so+0x151c2]  Java_sun_reflect_NativeMethodAccessorImpl_invoke0+0x32
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x2ae025]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x315
V  [libjvm.so+0x4030b9]  os::os_exception_wrapper(void (*)(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*), JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x19
V  [libjvm.so+0x2acc9f]  JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x2f
V  [libjvm.so+0x2ea715]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x2a5
V  [libjvm.so+0x2f115c]  jni_CallIntMethod+0xbc
C  [eclipse_1502.so+0x8521]  startJavaJNI+0x418
C  [eclipse_1502.so+0x99c0]  startJavaVM+0x24
C  [eclipse_1502.so+0x31b7]  run+0x59d
C  [eclipse+0x10ee]  strchr@@GLIBC_2.0+0x10ee

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK._soup_session_feature_detach(II)V+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK.soup_session_feature_detach(II)V+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebKit.create(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+892
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+81
j  org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl.isAvailable(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+12
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover$HoverControlCreator.doCreateInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+18
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator.createInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.getInformationControl()Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+176
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.internalShowInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/Rectangle;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+18
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.presentInformation()V+70
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractHoverInformationControlManager.presentInformation()V+64
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager.doPresentInformation()V+1
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$5.run()V+4
J 3988 C1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z (101 bytes) @ 0xb2b74410 [0xb2b742d0+0x140]
J 3993 C1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z (71 bytes) @ 0xb2b75e48 [0xb2b75d70+0xd8]
J 4117% C1 org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V (745 bytes) @ 0xb2bb76e0 [0xb2bb6080+0x1660]
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+256
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x5f076c00 JavaThread "Worker-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8937, stack(0x5f5af000,0x5f600000)]
  0x09d48c00 JavaThread "org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8932, stack(0x5eceb000,0x5ed3c000)]
  0x5af16c00 JavaThread "Worker-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8930, stack(0x5f225000,0x5f276000)]
  0x09b4a800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8743, stack(0x5addd000,0x5ae2e000)]
  0x09945000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8741, stack(0x5ab5e000,0x5abaf000)]
  0x5f485400 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8721, stack(0x5f838000,0x5f889000)]
  0x5f6ddc00 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8718, stack(0x5f72f000,0x5f780000)]
  0xb578a000 JavaThread "Worker-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8717, stack(0x6145e000,0x614af000)]
  0x09190800 JavaThread "Worker-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8716, stack(0x61625000,0x61676000)]
  0x61a5cc00 JavaThread "EMF Reference Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8711, stack(0x61388000,0x613d9000)]
  0x08ebcc00 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8707, stack(0x614af000,0x61500000)]
  0x08e34800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8705, stack(0x61676000,0x616c7000)]
  0x08de9000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8704, stack(0x616c7000,0x61718000)]
  0x08ddf800 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8703, stack(0x61718000,0x61769000)]
  0x08de6c00 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8702, stack(0x61769000,0x617ba000)]
  0x08da7c00 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=8701, stack(0x617ba000,0x6180b000)]
  0x08c73800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8699, stack(0x6188c000,0x618dd000)]
  0x08c71c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8698, stack(0x618dd000,0x6195e000)]
  0x08c70000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8697, stack(0x6195e000,0x619af000)]
  0x08c5d800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8696, stack(0x619af000,0x61a00000)]
  0x08c5c000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8695, stack(0x61b4d000,0x61b9e000)]
=>0x08c09400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=8689, stack(0xbf883000,0xbf8d3000)]

Other Threads:
  0x08c59400 VMThread [stack: 0x61b9e000,0x61c1f000] [id=8694]
  0x08c7e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x6180b000,0x6188c000] [id=8700]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 24637K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,  17% used [0x62200000, 0x63a0f560, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 67565K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  19% used [0x77750000, 0x7b94b5a8, 0x7b94b600, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 53504K, used 53256K [0xa2200000, 0xa5640000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 53504K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa5602158, 0xa5602200, 0xa5640000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0x61f7f000,0x62200000] byte_map_base: 0x61c6e000

Polling page: 0xb7722000

Code Cache  [0xb232e000, 0xb2c26000, 0xb432e000)
 total_blobs=4383 nmethods=4164 adapters=153 free_code_cache=23618Kb largest_free_block=24167616

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 745.005 Thread 0x08c71c00 4329             org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeBinding::findSuperTypeOriginatingFrom (411 bytes)
Event: 745.007 Thread 0x08c71c00 nmethod 4329 0xb29a0348 code [0xb29a0560, 0xb29a0eec]
Event: 745.008 Thread 0x08c71c00 4330             org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.HashtableOfArrayToObject::getIndex (64 bytes)
Event: 745.008 Thread 0x08c71c00 nmethod 4330 0xb299fec8 code [0xb299ffe0, 0xb29a0158]
Event: 745.009 Thread 0x08c71c00 4331   !         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JarPackageFragmentRoot::computeChildren (310 bytes)
Event: 745.013 Thread 0x08c71c00 nmethod 4331 0xb2c1cbc8 code [0xb2c1d090, 0xb2c1ecc8]
Event: 745.029 Thread 0x08c71c00 4332 %           sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerDataReader::read @ 11 (83 bytes)
Event: 745.030 Thread 0x08c71c00 nmethod 4332% 0xb299f648 code [0xb299f7a0, 0xb299fa5c]
Event: 745.032 Thread 0x08c71c00 4333             sun.text.normalizer.CharTrie::unserialize (74 bytes)
Event: 745.033 Thread 0x08c71c00 nmethod 4333 0xb2c21388 code [0xb2c214d0, 0xb2c218bc]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 550.809 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=18 (full 17):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 2821K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   2% used [0x62200000, 0x624c1490, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 66139K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  18% used [0x77750000, 0x7b7e6d18, 0x7b7e6e00, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 48128K, used 47902K [0xa2200000, 0xa5100000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 48128K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa50c78d8, 0xa50c7a00, 0xa5100000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 551.106 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=19 (full 18):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 0K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   0% used [0x62200000, 0x62200000, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 66139K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  18% used [0x77750000, 0x7b7e6e30, 0x7b7e7000, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 48128K, used 47902K [0xa2200000, 0xa5100000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 48128K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa50c78d8, 0xa50c7a00, 0xa5100000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 610.810 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=19 (full 18):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 5620K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   4% used [0x62200000, 0x6277d0c8, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 66139K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  18% used [0x77750000, 0x7b7e6e30, 0x7b7e7000, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 48128K, used 47902K [0xa2200000, 0xa5100000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 48128K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa50c78d8, 0xa50c7a00, 0xa5100000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 611.107 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=20 (full 19):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 0K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   0% used [0x62200000, 0x62200000, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 66139K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  18% used [0x77750000, 0x7b7e6f68, 0x7b7e7000, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 48128K, used 47902K [0xa2200000, 0xa5100000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 48128K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa50c78d8, 0xa50c7a00, 0xa5100000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 671.109 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=20 (full 19):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 2821K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   2% used [0x62200000, 0x624c1490, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 66139K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  18% used [0x77750000, 0x7b7e6f68, 0x7b7e7000, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 48128K, used 47902K [0xa2200000, 0xa5100000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 48128K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa50c78d8, 0xa50c7a00, 0xa5100000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 671.462 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=21 (full 20):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 0K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   0% used [0x62200000, 0x62200000, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 57925K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  16% used [0x77750000, 0x7afe1730, 0x7afe1800, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 47872K, used 47869K [0xa2200000, 0xa50c0000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 47872K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa50bf6b8, 0xa50bf800, 0xa50c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 727.464 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=21 (full 20):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 52802K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,  37% used [0x62200000, 0x65590988, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 57925K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  16% used [0x77750000, 0x7afe1730, 0x7afe1800, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 51968K, used 51967K [0xa2200000, 0xa54c0000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 51968K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa54bffc8, 0xa54c0000, 0xa54c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 727.770 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=22 (full 21):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 0K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   0% used [0x62200000, 0x62200000, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 66822K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  19% used [0x77750000, 0x7b8919d8, 0x7b891a00, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 51968K, used 51967K [0xa2200000, 0xa54c0000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 51968K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa54bffc8, 0xa54c0000, 0xa54c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 732.826 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=22 (full 21):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 11111K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   7% used [0x62200000, 0x62cd9ca0, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 66822K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  19% used [0x77750000, 0x7b8919d8, 0x7b891a00, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52412K [0xa2200000, 0xa5540000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 52480K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa552f1e8, 0xa552f200, 0xa5540000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 733.116 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=23 (full 22):
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 0K [0x62200000, 0x6ccc0000, 0x77750000)
  eden space 139904K,   0% used [0x62200000, 0x62200000, 0x6aaa0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x6bbb0000, 0x6bbb0000, 0x6ccc0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x6aaa0000, 0x6aaa0000, 0x6bbb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 67565K [0x77750000, 0x8ccb0000, 0xa2200000)
   the space 349568K,  19% used [0x77750000, 0x7b94b5a8, 0x7b94b600, 0x8ccb0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52412K [0xa2200000, 0xa5540000, 0xb2200000)
   the space 52480K,  99% used [0xa2200000, 0xa552f1e8, 0xa552f200, 0xa5540000)
No shared spaces configured.
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63402260 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x634025d0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63402940 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63402c98 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63402ff0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63403340 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63403750 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63403a98 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.308 Thread 0x09b4a800 Threw 0x63403de0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp:591
Event: 744.988 Thread 0x09e2a400 Threw 0x63685328 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-i586/jdk7u67/1368/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp:347

Events (10 events):
Event: 745.064 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 745.064 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 745.067 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize
Event: 745.068 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize done
Event: 745.069 loading class 0x09d773f8
Event: 745.069 loading class 0x09d773f8 done
Event: 745.103 loading class 0xb4e353e8
Event: 745.104 loading class 0xb4e353e8 done
Event: 745.122 loading class 0x09e3e9d8
Event: 745.122 loading class 0x09e3e9d8 done
```

Comment: Please try to solve this error.. its very urgent. please....

Comment: See my answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/512044/247396 and others as well if needed

Comment: configuration>config.ini ?

Comment: What is configuration>config.ini ?

Comment: Thanks a lot....error cleared out